# Empty space in UIImageView

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview, uitableview

I have a tableview, in there are cells where each cell has an image.

The images are from different sizes. So when I make a cell, I have to give the UIImageView a constraint for the width and height.

now what I want is: when the images gets loaded into the UIImageView of the cell, the size of the UIImageView should adjust to the image itself.

I am experimenting for the last 2 days but can't fix it. The cells in the table keep having empty spaces because of the constraints.

The code I am using to populate the cell:

```
class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var productTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
var orgframe = UIImageView()


func configureCellWith(product: Product){
    orgframe.frame.size = CGSizeMake(400, 600)
    productImageView.image = product.image
    productDescriptionLabel.text = product.description
    productTitleLabel.text = product.title

    var urlstring = product.imageURL

    ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlstring as String, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
        //self.productImageView.frame.size = (image?.size)!

        self.productImageView.image = image!


    })


}


}
```

The constraints of the UIImageview:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give productImageView a fixed height constraint, and hook it up to an IBOutlet. Then when you're ready to load your image, you can do this:

```
self.productImageHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

You'll want to make sure the surrounding views/labels are pinned to the edges of the imageview so they will arrange themselves according to the image size.

Comment: I did and it helped BUT: All the elements moved down, except for the seperator. So the size of the cell didn't adjust to it's new size.. How do I do that?

Comment: In heightForRowAtIndexPath, return the height of the cell based on the image height (or some default height if the image hasn't downloaded yet).

Comment: I am returning a default height, but after that I want to update the height of the cell exactly to delete all the empty spaces. So the height must be just as low as possible. What command can I use for this, from the producttableviewcell.swift file, where I configure the cell